# How do I use foreach() on a control to manipulate another control?

Tags: c#

I'm making a UI in winform, I'm using VS2015 to create the winform.  The UI is subdivided into multiple pages by a tab control.  In one of the tab page along with other things (picture box, text box, buttons etc.) I have 8 check box named cb1 ~ cb8, and 8 horizontal scroll bar named scrjoint1 ~ scrjoint8.

The scroll bar is used to set the angle value in RotateTransform() for objects drawn in the picture box.  What I wanted to do is:

1.If cb1 is check, scrjoint1 is 0.

- Else scrl1 is whatever the user set it to be.

2.If cb2 is check, scrljoint2 is 0.

- Else scrljoint2 is whaterver the user set it to be.

3.And so on for the other checkbox and horizontal scroll.

Instead of checking each check box individually and then assigning the value of scrljint respectively, what I had in mind is to achieve by using foreach() function as in the following format:

```
private void scrJoint_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var cbControl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (cbControl is CheckBox)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)cbControl).Checked)
            {
                //set scrolJoint1~8 = 0 according to checkbox that is checked
            }
            else
            {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the current issue I'm having now is,when there is one or more check box that is checked (let say cb1 and cb2 is check) how do I set the respective horizontal scroll bar (`scrJoint1` and `scrJoint2`) to 0 in:

```
if (((CheckBox)cbControl).Checked)
{
    //set scrolJoint1~8 = 0 according to checkbox that 
}
else
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

Couple more questions I liked to ask in respect to what I'm trying to do:

1.Is using `foreach()` a good idea in what I'm trying to achieve?

2.Would it be better if I just check it one by one using If-Else (although I don't want to use this method, because I might need to include more check boxes and scroll bars later, and the code will get ridiculously long very fast).

3.Is there another more cunning ways (clean and short method is preferred) of doing what I wanted to achieve that you guys can suggest (if there is, can you provide an example).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have logic on the check event of each checkbox, and there set the related scroll bar position and disable it?

Comment: one idea is to combine/place the chkBox and scroll in/onto a single control (ie a group) and have 8 of those, whence that control encapsulates the relationship between the checkBox and the scroll.  Another option is to set the Tag property of the chkBox to point to its related scroll and use that.

Comment: The code doesn't win any prizes, but it isn't wrong.  There are too many ways to do this, the clean way is not the short way.  It is clean when you create arrays in the constructor.  It is short when you use stringly typing by parsing the Name property.

Comment: Hi  @OfirW ,  Sorry I'm a bit confused.  Can you please elaborate on what do you meant by having the logic on the check event of each checkbox?  I'm still very new to c# so need I don't always get what others suggested instantly.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are doing right approach. If possible use @Ofir Winegarten suggestion. else wise you can little bit modify your method.and please place proper exception handling as well.

```
this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(row => row.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CheckBox)) && ((CheckBox)row).Checked).All(row => SetScroll(((CheckBox)row)));
```

where setScroll is a method 
or

```
foreach (var cbControl in this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(row => row.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CheckBox)) && ((CheckBox)row).Checked))
```

Answer (score 0):

A Simple solution might be:

Subscribe to the `CheckedChanged` event of each of the individual checkboxes.
Inside these methods, set the related `scrollbar.Value` to 0 and disable it (`scrollBar.Enabled = false`).

```
private void CbOnCheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    SetScrollBarValue(this.cb1, this.scrjoint1)
}

private void CbOnCheckedChanged_2(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    SetScrollBarValue(this.cb2, this.scrjoint2)
}

....

private static void SetScrollBarValue(CheckBox cb, ScrollBar sb)
{
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        sb.Value = 0;
        sb.Enabled = false;
    }
    else sb.Enabled = true;
}
```

You will have the same method of each checkbox.

A more generalized way would be to subscribe to the different checkboxes events with the same method and there, using one of the techniques suggested above, get the related scrollbar. In the following example I chose the shortest one - search by name:

```
private void CbOnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) sender;
    ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar) this.Controls.Find("scrJoint" + cb.Name.Last());
    SetScrollBarValue(cb, sb);
}
```

Another quite short way is to store the id in the `Tag` property of each control (`Checkbox` and `ScrollBar`) and then using linq get the scrollbar:

```
private void CbOnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) sender;
    ScrollBar sb = 
        this.Controls.OfType<ScrollBar>().Single(bar => (int)bar.Tag ==(int)cb.Tag);    
    SetScrollBarValue(cb, sb);
}
```

Comment: ahhh, I see what you meant.  I'll give this a try.  thanks